# How to populate MySQL all table with vb Combo boxes and corresponding values with text boxes

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am making a application on the VB form where I want to connect my all the MySQL database with the Combo boxes and Text Boxes and corresponding values of all the tables with the text boxes.

Please let me know how can I populate all my database tables with one Combo boxes and another combo box with the inside value of one table and text boxes will show the corresponding values of the tables.

My database is as under:

```
Schema Name :Surveys.

Tables :CES-2005
        CES -2009
CES-2010 etc
```

Values in side the tables are as under:

```
idces2005             state name      BCG       DPT          NOOE
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to populate the textboxes with information from your database use the following:

```
 TextBox1.Text = TableName.Row(0)("Name of column").toString()
```

Comment: Thank you so much but I want to keep all the tables of my database in one combo box then corresponding values of the tables in text box .So once I select the value form the combo box it will reflect the respective value in text box

Comment: so instead of "Name of column" use a variable that gets the index of the item you selected in the combo box. Put this under the function comboBox_SelectedIndexChange